# How to change Server characterset and Db characterset?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to set value 'Server characterset' and 'Db characterset' from 'latin1' to 'utf-8',I search Google for a long time,still can't solve the problem.

When I add 'default-character-set=utf8' below '[client]' and '[mysqld]' in the file **'/etc/my.cnf'** it doesn't work.

I found some articles said add the values in the file **'/etc/mysql/my.cnf'**.But I can't restart the mysql when I do that(can stop but not start when I use **'service mysql restart'**),the error message:'**ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'**

Can someone help me?

Comment: What server and OS are you using?

Comment: @30secondstosam 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You should add two lines of code under [mysqld] in my.ini file.then rebot mysql server.

[mysqld]

character-set-server = utf8
collation_server = utf8_general_ci